# Why I'm facing this error ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint 02264. 00000 - "name already used by an existing constraint" *Cause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Here is my code, can anyone will be fixed this error? I have tried my best to fix this issue but with regret, I get failed. I'm using oracle 11g.

```
{  CREATE TABLE ProjectX
  (
     ProjectID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(40),
     DepartmentID NUMBER,

     CONSTRAINT Department_ID FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID)
     REFERENCES Department(DepartmentID)
  );
}
```

Comment: `Initial` is a SQL reserved word, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Either delimit it as `"initial"`, or - even better - chose another column name.

Comment: Tip: Don't store dates in varchar2 columns, use proper date data type!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your column name Initial Change it to "initial" or give any other column name. You can't use a reserved word as your column name. That's why oracle giving an error as an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a reserved word, you can use it between double quotes, but that is where life becomes complicated. Refer below:

[Oracle Reserved Words](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621)